# How do I get graphics working with Linux on my Braswell NUC box?

Tags: fedora, intel-graphics

Fedora Live (23) works okay for me[*].  But if I install Fedora, the login screen never comes up.  It goes to black/"no signal", flipping between the two every few seconds.  It can't have downloaded some bad updates, because I didn't connect it to the network.

I'm using the NUC5CPYH model.   I thought the display would work nicely under Linux, because it's Intel hardware[**].  What's the problem?

---

[*] Ignoring a few kernel messages `*ERROR* timed out waiting for Punit DDR DVFS request`.
[**] Though I'm primarily using this to replace a headless ARM server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: this appears to have been fixed after an update from 4.2 series kernel to 4.3 series kernel.

Yay!  I no longer need to disable Wayland.

---

TLDR: disable Wayland in `/etc/gdm/custom.conf`.  (Step-by-step instructions [here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-wayland-gdm-issue-fedora/))

---

[Phoronix](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Intel-Braswell-Fedora-Ubuntu) said Ubuntu works.  Unfortunately Fedora 22 didn't, even though you'd expect them to have newer drivers.  Commenters said "Ubuntu hacked the 3.19 kernel with a 2nd driver for Skylake/Braswell."

I was very frustrated that I couldn't find logs from X, even in `journalctl -b`...

because Fedora Workstation is enabling Wayland for the login screen (so it gets some testing).  The difference with the live media is that it doesn't enable Wayland.

I opened a report for this [in the Fedora issue tracker](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1294812)

Comment: It then makes sense to apply updates, retry Wayland - and if it still does not work report a bug at bugzilla and share the link to the issue here.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me! I would like to get this fixed (I'd also like it highlighted somewhere you'd expect it, like the installation troubleshooting or the release notes!)  Unfortunately I get lots of EGL errors in the journal (Wayland/gdm).  The suspicion is EGL in Mesa or whatever Wayland uses that X doesn't, wasn't implemented bug-free in the first place for this chipset.  I'm inclined to report this against Wayland to get it triaged... I suspect it's going to require a developer who has this hardware.

Comment: @maxschlepzig - done.